# MSQL database wp_postmeta has meta key tve_revision

Tags: database, mysql

My DB exceeded the limit, it's postmeta table which has a lot of meta keys starting with tve_revision_'something'

Where do they come from? Could it be Thrives Leads?

Comment: Sounds plausible. I'd search all of the files in your sit for "tve_revision", e.g. with grep.

Comment: What post types are they attached to?

Comment: "My DB exceeded the limit" -> change the limit?